# Question about inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

if: $-2 \leq x \leq 3$ , then what interval does $x^{2}$ belongs to ?

my solution was $: 0 \leq x^{2} \leq 9$ according to high school knowledge.

if it true why did the negative side turn to be 0$?$ what is the rule?

Comment: You always have $x^2 \ge 0$ (for real $x$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that a square is always $\geq 0$. What I would do is split in 2 cases (when $x$ is positive or negative)

If $0\leq x\leq 3$, then $0\leq x^2\leq 9$.

If $-2\leq  x\leq 0$, then $0\leq x^2\leq 4$ (think about it).

So, by taking the "union of the sets" $0\leq x^2\leq 9$ and  $0\leq x^2\leq 4$, you get all the possible values of $x^2$. You get $0\leq x^2\leq 9$.

Comment: Congrats on 3K rep! +1

Answer (score 4):

Remember that $a\leq b \iff a^2\leq b^2$ only if $a,b\geq 0$.

If $x\geq 0$ then from $x\leq 3$ after squaring, we get $x^2\leq 9$

and if $x\leq 0$ then from $-2\leq x$ thus $-x\leq 2$ so after squaring we get $x^2\leq 4$.

So $$0\leq x^2\leq 9$$

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In this case you can consider the graph of $x^2$ to understand the relevant interval and the lower bound $0$.